# Not able to add list items to HTML Document

Tags: javascript, dom, async-await, fetch

I am using `fetch()` command to get an array of data in JSON format. I am using function `fetchURL()` to get data in JSON format. I use `async-await`. Then in each data received I am trying to add it's `login` field to an ordered list that I have created in the HTML file.

I have made a `createListItem()` function to find the ordered list tag in the HTML file and append in it the `login` field. But first I try to store all the `login` fields in an array `arr`. But I am not able to store the `login` fields in it.

But when I directly use `createListItem()` function to create a list item with **login**" field as text I am able to add these fields to the ordered list and hence I get the ordered list.
I am commenting out the lines that get me direct Output on the browser window when I do not store the `login` fields in the `arr`:

Code:

```
function createListItem(text) {
  const parent = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
  const entry = document.createElement("li");
  entry.textContent = text;
  parent[0].appendChild(entry);
}
const url = "https://api.github.com/users ";
async function fetchURL() {
  return (await fetch(url)).json();
}
let arr = [];
async function createList() {
  const data = await fetchURL();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //createListItem(`${data[i].login}`);
    arr.push(data[i].login);
  }
}
createList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the data in array, you need to create list after you call `createList()` function:

```
createList().then(function(){
    arr.forEach(element => {
        createListItem(element);
    });
});
```

you can also define `arr` in the `createList` function and return that then your code would be like this:

```
async function createList() {
  let arr = [];
  const data = await fetchURL();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    //createListItem(`${data[i].login}`);
    arr.push(data[i].login);
  }
  return arr;
}
createList().then(arr=>{
    arr.forEach(element => {
        createListItem(element);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your objective with just one async function:

```js
const url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

async function getList(u){
  const arr=(await fetch(u).then(r=>r.json())).map(e=>e.username);
  document.querySelector("ol").innerHTML=arr.map(u=>`<li>${u}</li>`).join("");
  console.log(arr);
}

getList(url);
```

```html
<h2>List of login names</h2>
<ol></ol>
<p>end of page</p>
```

In the above snippet I used the public resource provided by typicode.com and extracted the property of `username` instead of `login`.